# 'list' object has no attribute 'encode' when storing list of values in blob on azure

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to enter multiple values in my blob on azure.

I have four values which i want to enter in a blob.

```
firstname
lastname
address
contact
```

So I have written code like this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import PublicAccess

firstName = u'john'
lastName  = u'doe'
address = u'new york'
contact = u'2222222222'

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='myAccountName', account_key='myAccountkey')
block_blob_service.create_container('mycontainer')
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('mycontainer','myblockblob',[firstName,lastName,address,contact])
```

But I am getting below error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Full error:

```
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
Exception Location: D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-
packages\azure\storage\blob\blockblobservice.py in create_blob_from_text, 
line 773
Python Executable:  D:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
[u'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\env\\Lib\\site-packages',
'.',
'D:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
'D:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'D:\\Python27\\lib',
'D:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'D:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
'D:\\Python27',
'D:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot']
Server time:    Wed, 15 Nov 2017 21:43:33 +0000
```

is there a way I can get these values in my blob.

Comment: Provide the full error message including the stack trace. Also, you should be providing a [mcve]. What is `BlockBlobService`? As it stands, your example would throw a `NameError`

Comment: But it *seems* like whatever `.create_blob_from_text` is, it requires some sort of string object for the third argument.

Comment: A list is not a blob. A bytes object is. You need to serialize your list, e.g. by *pickling*.

Comment: update my question

Comment: (And then use `create_blob_from_bytes`)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala looking at the API docs, there seems to be a `create_blob_from_text` method which defaults to a utf8 encoding, so you can just pass it a string. But yes, likely, they want to pickle then send the bytes. Or maybe JSON?

Comment: ya maybe JSON would be ok too :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give [`BlockBlobService.create_blob_from_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage) a string. You could, for example, use:

```
my_list = [firstName, lastName, address, contact]
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('mycontainer', 'myblockblob', ','.join(my_list))
```

to create a comma-separated string of the values from your list, then create a blob from that.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, serialize your data in a pickle or JSON and then use `create_blob_from_bytes`.